# Is there a text field where moderators can specify reason for deleting an answer?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools

When a moderator deletes an answer (not the whole question), is there a text field where they can specify reason?

Searching related discussions here suggests that such an (optional) field does exist when deleting questions. But what about answers?

Comment: Just to confirm, and someone will ask - there's no such field for questions either. I double checked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope. We need to rely on memory or understanding the scopes of our sites in both cases. In theory we could probably throw in a comment, or even do a flag for "audit" purposes, but generally its self evident enough that I can look at a post I deleted as a new mod, say 5 years ago, or look at a post another moderator deleted, and have a reasonable idea why it was deleted.

It's also worth remembering there's cases where a post can be deleted without mod intervention, either by high rep members of the community (after a post is downvoted), or by flag (spam) or even by a user themselves, and none of these paths have a way to annotate why a post was deleted either.

Comment: For copied posts (plagiarism or inadvertent copying) I leave a comment as I delete, for documentation purposes. Because those come up on Meta most; *Why was this highly voted super-helpful well written thorough answer deleted by a moderator?!? Can we not just torch all moderators!?!eleven!?*

Answer (score 2):

I’ve seen comments used by moderators to communicate why a post was deleted. This is usually done for the benefit of the OP of the post, so that they know what was wrong with their post and can avoid making the same mistake again (and maybe fix the post so it can be undeleted). This is effective because notifications of comments from moderators are not removed from a user’s inbox when the post is deleted. Moderators can also post comments without the post needing to be undeleted or unlocked. Also note that any users with the ability to see deleted posts can see comments on deleted posts but not deleted comments (which can only be seen by moderators, not that I’m aware of anyone using deleted comments to communicate with other moderators).

Comment: I would need to test to double check, but my understanding is that notifications from comments which the moderator has placed on a post prior to deletion are removed from the user's inbox when the post is deleted, just like everyone else's. However, moderators can leave a comment on posts after the post has been deleted. The notification from moderator comments placed *after* deletion are added to the user's inbox, and the user sees them as normal inbox notifications. So, yes, moderators can communicate something on a deleted post, but the comment needs to be placed after the post is deleted.